# recursive function - array values disappears

Tags: arrays, powershell, recursion

Before calling a recursive function (`RecursiveWebs()`) `$webinfo.Count` is 1. During the execution of recursive function, `Count` is increased, but as soon as the recursive function is completed and control returns to the main function, `$webinfo.Count` again decreases to 1.

```
function RecursiveWebs($web) {
    $Properties = @{
        Title = $web.Title
        URL = $web.Url
    }

    $webinfo += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties       
    foreach ($w in $web.Webs) {
        if ($w.Webs.Count -gt 0) {
            RecursiveWebs $w
        }
    }
}

$global:webinfo = @() 
$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All
foreach ($site in $sites) {
    Write-Host $site.Url
    try {
        $Properties = @{
            Title = $site.Title
            URL = $site.Url            
            NoOfSubsites = $site.Webs.Count        
        }    

        $webinfo += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties

        if ($site.Webs.Count -gt 0) {
            RecursiveWebs $site
        }        
    } catch  {
        Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: You "reset" `$global:webinfo` each time the function runs? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `$webinfo` in your `RecursiveWebs` function is not the same variable as `$global:webinfo` in the top-level scope of the script.  You need to use `$global:webinfo` in your function as well for the changes to be visible outside of the function.  Even better, avoid the scoping issues entirely by, for example, passing the array as as parameter and adding to it via that reference.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am not resetting $webinfo. My understanding is that if variable scope is global, it should be same variablein the main and inside recursive function

Comment: @BACON Just to confirm, i change parameters of recursive function -  RecursiveWebs form RecursiveWebs($web) to RecursiveWebs($web,$webinfo). Right?

Comment: @Farhan Correct.

Comment: @BACON Tried, not working. Same issue. $webinfo,count increase but as soon leaves recursive function, count decrease to same as before call of recursive function

Comment: @Farhan And you've changed `$global:webinfo` to `$webinfo`?

Comment: @BACON yes. Changed `$global:webinfo` to `$webinfo`

Comment: I think we need you to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44036921/edit) your question to include your updated code before we can do much more to help you.

Comment: thanks @TheMadTechnician

Answer (score 1):

Replaces $webinfo with $Global:webinfo everywhere in the code and it did the trick